# Offset SUM of Data by -1 month of User Inputs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to modify a piece of code where the user input 3 fields: Year, Start Month, and End Month. It will then SUM the number of pallets that were sent within the start/end month date range.

I'd like to modify it so that it pulls information one month prior to what the user entered.

**Example 1:**

@Year: 2022, @StartMonth: 1, @EndMonth: 5

It should pull data from December 1 2021 to April 30 2022.

**Example 2:**

@Year: 2021, @StartMonth: 1, @EndMonth: 12

It should pull data from December 1 2020 to November 30, 2021.

I included the original code and I am unsure how to modify it because of how many inputs the user has to enter.

```
Original Code:
@Year int, @StartMonth int, @EndMonth int
SELECT        SUM(Pallets) AS Expr1, DATEPART(mm, Date) AS Expr2, DATEPART(yyyy, Date) AS Expr3
FROM            dbo.PalettesData
WHERE        (DATEPART(mm, Date) BETWEEN @StartMonth AND @EndMonth) AND (DATEPART(yyyy, Date) = @Year)
GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, Date), DATEPART(yyyy, Date)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: This code is somewhat flawed, how would you handle months that straddle a year boundary? It's also not sargable, you need to define a start and end *date* and check the `Date` column is within the range using `>= and <` operators.

Comment: Also might be worth this one. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In scenario like above, i always prefer to construct dates from `@StartMonth` , `@EndMonth` and `@Year` variables.

Below code demonstrate how to get dates from provided variables.

```
Declare @StartMonth int=1 , @EndMonth int=10 , @Year int = 2020
---Expected resultset should be between 2019-12-01 till 2020-09-30
select 
dateadd(month,-1,cast(cast(@Year as varchar)+case when @StartMonth <10 then '-0' else '-' end+cast(@StartMonth as varchar)+'-01' as date)) startdate,
dateadd(day,-1,cast(cast(@Year as varchar)+case when @EndMonth <10 then '-0' else '-' end+cast(@EndMonth as varchar)+'-01' as date)) as EndDate
```

Having said that, you can modify your where clause as below ( Since sample data is not provided, I couldn't test the where clause. ):

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN 
dateadd(month,-1,cast(cast(@Year as varchar)+case when @StartMonth <10 then '-0' else '-' end+cast(@StartMonth as varchar)+'-01' as date))
AND
dateadd(day,-1,cast(cast(@Year as varchar)+case when @EndMonth <10 then '-0' else '-' end+cast(@EndMonth as varchar)+'-01' as date))
```

Comment: This will work great, thank you!